# What configuration settings need to be done to fix Apache - MongoDB connectivity issues caused by SE Linux?

Tags: linux, apache, networking

I have Apache 2.4 running on CentOS 7. SE Linux is enabled. The application uses Laravel (Lumen), and connects to MongoDB on another server. All our servers are in Google cloud.The applications fails to load the web page and lumen.log has errors like this `lumen.ERROR: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce`set): [Failed to resolve 'mongo.***.***'] in /var/www/***/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php:612`

If SE Linux is disabled, it works.  I have the following sebools set

```
httpd_can_network_connect --> on
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
httpd_can_network_relay --> on
```

Anything else to be set? How to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed setroubleshoot and setools using
`yum install setroubleshoot setools`
and used it to analyze audit.log.
`sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log`
It turned out that apache was not able to read /etc/hosts and go to MongoDB server.
`ls -lZ /etc/hosts
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 /etc/hosts`
Executing
`restorecon  /etc/hosts`
Changed it to
`-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:net_conf_t:s0  /etc/hosts`

and fixed the issue.